# Set manufacturer in REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-attributes

I am trying to set the manufacturer for import logic (REST API) and I have the manufacturer name. However the API is expecting an int for the manufacturer attribute.

Is there a way to programmatically set the manufacturer per product or first set/get the manufacturers and then use their IDs for the REST product set?

The error I get:

```
{"message":"Error occurred during \"custom_attributes\" processing. Attribute \"manufacturer\" has invalid value. Invalid type for value: \"A manufacturer name\". Expected Type: \"int\"."}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1` API (http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) to get the product option value IDs, and then send these IDs as the custom attribute value.

For example:

```
GET /rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/options
```

Might return:

```json
[
  {
    "label": " ",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "label": "Apple",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "label": "Google",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "label": "Microsoft",
    "value": "3"
  },
]
```

You can then use these values in your next PUT/POST requests.